# Create local copy of DynamoDB Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, dynamo-local

I have a DynamoDB table named Entry. I want to create a local copy to my PC: Local_Entry.

In simplified words, I want to have a lambda function which will update an entry to Local_Entry whenever an update happens in the web dynamoDB table.

The main aim of this task is to access the entries in the Entry table even when I am offline, depending upon the fetched data.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using S3?

Comment: Switch AmazonDynamoDBConfig.serverURl pointing to "http://localhost:8000" this should write all data to the local dynamodb. I think you may  have to initialise a new instance of the AmazonDynamoDBClient pointing to the config pointing to the localhost.